# Why doesn't my $.getScript work in node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

I am very new to JavaScript. And I am trying to execute a .js file which uses jquery to load other scripts with node. My .js file is called `test.js` and as follows:

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
    $.getScript("./svmjs/lib/svm.js").done(function(){
        console.log("loaded!")
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("failed!")
    });
})
```

I am trying to run it on mac with command `node test.js`, but I get nothing output in the console. What am I doing wrong here? My impression is that with `done` or `fail` it will at least output something. But I get nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious: is there a reason you aren't just using `require`?

Comment: @MikeC No particular reasons. This is the solution I get while searching the internet. And I guess in order to require, the script has to be installed? Some of the scripts are my own scripts which I don't know how to install them either.

Comment: To use `require`, the files just have to exist in your file system relative to where you launch the file from. Either that or you install them using `npm install`, like what I assume you did with `jsdom`. It's very rare that you'll even need to use jQuery on the server side.

Comment: No worries. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getScript` is used to load in scripts on the browser side. In Node.js you have a better tool: `require`.

Just `require` your modules directly instead of using jQuery. In fact, it's unlikely you'll need jQuery at all.

Change

```
$.getScript("./svmjs/lib/svm.js").done(function(){
    console.log("loaded!")
}).fail(function(){
    console.log("failed!")
});
```

to

```
require('./svmjs.lib.svm.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will probably not work in Node.js, as it depends heavily on the browser DOM, which is not present in Node.js (there is no `window` object or other code, native to a browser environment only). Also, you do not need jQuery for loading NPM packages.

Instead, you should do something like this:

1. Navigate to the project directory in a command line. Generate a `package.json` if you have not done that already by running `npm init` and following the instructions.
2. Register `node-svm`, a Node.js-compatible version of SVM, as a dependency by running `npm install --save node-svm`.
3. Run `npm install` to download `node-svm` and its dependencies. They will be installed into the `node_modules` subdirectory.
4. In `index.js` or whatever the entry point of your project is (defined in the `main` property of `package.json` follow this example and you should be good to go.
5. Run `node index.js` and check console output.

## index.js

```
var svm = require('node-svm');

var xor = [
    [[0, 0], 0],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], 0]
];

// initialize a new predictor 
var clf = new svm.CSVC();

clf.train(xor).done(function () {
    // predict things 
    xor.forEach(function(ex){
        var prediction = clf.predictSync(ex[0]);
        console.log('%d XOR %d => %d', ex[0][0], ex[0][1], prediction);
    });
});
```

## Output

```
0 XOR 0 => 0
0 XOR 1 => 1
1 XOR 0 => 1
1 XOR 1 => 0
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm assuming that jQuery/$ is `undefined`. You need to install it into your project using:

`npm install jquery --save`

After you do that, add `var $ = require('jquery');` to the top of your file.

Also, if you're not working in the browser and using strictly Node then you will need to use `require` instead of jQuery's getScript function. getScript is more suited for browser applications.